# Styling text within a div similar to links

Tags: css

I have the following breadcrumb code.

```css
#breadcrumb{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;}

#breadcrumb a{background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:4px;
  margin-right:10px;}
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a><a href="parent-catagory.html" title="Parent Catagory">Parent Catagory</a>Child Catagory
</div>
```

I have styled the 'Home' and 'Parent Catagory' links to have solid colour backgrounds. I would like to style the 'Child Catagory' text with a slightly different colour solid background from the two links. All three elements of the breadcrumb should have gaps between them and should not be touching.

The 'Child Catagory' text is not surrounded by `<span>` so I am unsure how to achieve this.

If I add styling to the surrounding 'breadcrumb' div, the space between the links is affected.

I need to style just the text in the 'breadcrumb' div, not the div itself and not the links.

Comment: Please post your css

Comment: Are you able to edit the html?

Comment: Hi, I could edit the html, and just add a span around the text I would like to style, but... I don't want to. I'm sure this is possible, as I think I have found a similar question before, but I can't remember the wording to search for it again.

Comment: I am mistaken, the previous answer that I am referring to was to hide all text in a div without hiding the link using `visibility: collapse;
white-space: pre;`

Answer (score 3):

This is a terrible hacky approach and should not be used. I strongly recommend wrapping the last bit of the breadcrumb in a span and styling the span.

```css
#breadcrumb {
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
#breadcrumb a {
  background:green;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
#breadcrumb a:after {
  content: "";
  background: white;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -5px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="parent-catagory.html" title="Parent Catagory">Parent Catagory</a>
  Child Catagory
</div>
```

### Edit

If you know the width of the last element, you can do the following:

```css
#breadcrumb:after {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 99px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#breadcrumb {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#breadcrumb a{
  background:#ccc;
  padding:4px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a><a href="parent-catagory.html" title="Parent Catagory">Parent Catagory</a>Child Catagory
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I see where you are going with this, but it doesn't quite give me what I need as the white after the links needs to be transparent really.

Comment: @RouthMedia I've extended my answer to take into account you wanting a transparent background.

Comment: As a side-note: For `absolute`ly positioned inline-level elements — including pseudo-elements — the computed value of `display` is `block`. Therefore adding `display: inline-block` doesn't affect the element.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 - Edit the HTML

The question is: Can you edit the HTML?

The best thing to do would be to edit the HTML and add a surrounding div to the "Child Category" item, then style it.

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="parent-catagory.html" title="Parent Catagory">Parent Catagory</a>
    <div class="child">Child Category</div>
</div>
```

#### SCSS

```
#breadcrumb{
    a,
    .child{
        background: #f5f5f5;
        padding: 4px 7px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        &:first-child {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    }
    .child{
        display: inline-block;
        background: #222;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

#### CSS Output

```
#breadcrumb a, #breadcrumb .child {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
#breadcrumb a:first-child, #breadcrumb .child:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#breadcrumb .child {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEaPqx

### Option 2 -- Javascript workaround

Of course there are other ways using javascript like getting the value from another div and appending it to the breadcrumb div. The issue is that this is could eventually break if the HTML changes. It also depends on the content already on the page.

```
<div id="existing-child-category-text">Child Category</div>

<div id="breadcrumb">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="parent-catagory.html" title="Parent Catagory">Parent Catagory</a>
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
// Create the child element
var child_cat = document.createElement('div');

// Add a class name to the child element
child_cat.className = 'child';

// Add the text from the existing child category to the child div
child_cat.innerHTML = document.getElementById('existing-child-category-text').innerHTML;

// Add the new div to the breadcrumbs
document.getElementById('breadcrumb').appendChild(child_cat);
```

Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEaPqx

Ultimately I would assume that if you are able to edit javascript then you could also change the HTML which would be a way more robust solution.

### Option 3 -- Use Pseudo Elements

Try to avoid this but you could have a similar approach using css pseudo elements. but you would need to set the value via javascript or hardcode the value on css which is not the best solution.